# Can you install a program for all users using ClickOnce VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, publish

Can you install a program for "All Users" using Visual Studio ClickOnce Publishing?

I ran setup and was not given the option "Install for All users" => then I inspected the actual install directory and it was in the folder:

```
C:\Users\Patrick\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\Z5AWACYL.000\4EQB7LVJ.RXP\mapl..tion_0000000000000000_0001.0000_d31e4ada0d11807b\
```

So I think no other user will be allowed to run it.  How does one create a project installer that installs a program to all users?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a bunch of research the answer is No.

I figured out a really hack way to pull it off.  But it caused problems in production, specifically, I got calls from this guy, and he's like "Do I have to install the app for every user?",  Then later he would say, "User1 is running version X.X.X.1, but user2 is running X.X.X.2"  So it was a lot of work for disappointing results.

Answer (score 2):

Have you taken a look at this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997001.aspx